# white space in the left of the website

Tags: html, css

this is the html:

```css
html{
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    min-height: 100%; 
}
.header {
    background: url("bghero.png") no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    height: 200%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 70%;
}
#circle{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 4%;
}
#big{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 700%;
    top: 40%;
    color: white;
    right: 0%;
    width: 100%;

}
#sml{

}
#ham{
    text-align: center-right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    right:5%;
}
#src{
    text-align: center-right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.8%;
    right:11%;
}
#menu1{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    right: 6%;
        position: absolute;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
#menu2{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    right: 0%;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
        position: absolute;
}
#menu3{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: -6%;
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}

#lowerfoto{
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
=}
#fteweit{
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
}
#fterblk{
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="background">
        <img id="circle" src="circle.png" />
        <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">
        <p id="menu1">Home</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
        <p id="menu2">About</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
        <p id="menu3">Contact</p>
        </a>
        </div>
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><img id="src" src="src.png" /></a>
        <img id="ham" src="ham.png" />

        <div class="welcome">
            <p id="big">Web Design</p>
            <p id="sml">
                Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris <br />
                condimentum , ut fermentum massa justo sit amet <br />
                erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit <br />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <img id="lowerfoto" src="lower.png">    
    <div class="footer">
        <img id="fteweit" src="fterwit.png">
        <img id="fterblk" src="fterblk.png">
    </div>
```

and I have a white space in the right side of the website, and I can't get it off. What I did figured out, that the menu is making that space and when I remove the menu, there is no space. But I do need that menu, so what do I need to do in order that there will be no white space WHILE there is a menu?

how it looks like:
http://prntscr.com/ak745y

Comment: can you have jsfiddle link?

Comment: @satya I'm sorry, but what is that?

Comment: `text-align: center-right;` Does not compute ack! o_0

Comment: why = in css code?

Comment: Actually i need to test your issue , and until i am not able to debug, it is hard to fix it. JSfiddle is a kind of site useful for web developer where we can test htmls, css and others..

Comment: @Leothelion http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: Hereis the code of the css and html in jsfiddle: 

    https://jsfiddle.net/7kxrqs7u/

Comment: did you try this ?`body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`

Comment: your question is so confusing..in  your fiddle no images and which white space...where it is located..please be more specific

Comment: Actually it should come as the image you have posted..then i can debug

Comment: i asked why you used = sign in your code..can you please explain that?

Comment: ofcourse there are no images, cuz all of the images are on my computer. I  can try to upload them to the internet and link them if it will help.

Comment: and @Leothelion it wasnt on purpose, I deleted it.

Comment: ohh..but still did not get your issue..please put some more light on it..thanx

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ak78ae
http://prntscr.com/ak78ga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra space on the left-hand and right-hand side of the website is being caused by the default margin.

To prevent this:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; 
}
```

Update: Your ID `#menu3` is causing the issue. My suggestion would be to put the elements inside `ul` like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 40%;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 49%;"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu" style="margin-left: 58%;"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

    .menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 5.3%;
    }
```

Comment: yes I deleted the small white space, but there is still more white space in the right side of the web only.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable or change all the "right" & "margin-right" to 0 & add "left" attribute to seperate your elements.

```
#ham{

    text-align: center-right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;

**right:5%;**

}
->
#ham{
    text-align: center-right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
**right:0%;
  left: 10%**

}
---------------------
#src{
    text-align: center-right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.8%;
**right:11%;**

}
-----------------
#menu3{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
**right: -6%;**
    top: 5.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
```

Comment: It did remove the white space, but now how am I going to separate each menu from another, and each button from another? (ham from src and menu 1 from menu 2 and menu 3)

Comment: @kuyy check my answer for a solution which does that :)

Comment: @kuyy: Just add the left attribute to your HTML code. You can try sample code in my next answer.